# How to save a line of user inputted integers into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

How would I be able to take a group of numbers inputted on a single line by the user (however many they want) and put them in to an array?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Check Scanner - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 1):

You can let the user input the data as a String delimited by space (or other delimiters)

After you receive the string of input, tokenized the data into tokens where you can store them into a data structure of your choice (array, array list..etc).

You may use `String.split()` when tokenizing them.

**For example:**

```
String input = sc.nextLine();
String[] tokens = input.split(" ");
int[] data = new int[tokens.length];

for(int x=0; x<tokens.length; x++)
    data[x] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[x]);

//Input: 11 22 33 44
//data[0] will be 11
//data[1] will be 22
//data[2] will be 33 and so on
```

;

Comment: And please take more care next time.